# How to call a python file, that needs to import packages?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-import, python-embedding

I'm following a tutorial to call python code from a C++ program from [the python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding).

Everything works just fine when trying to call the `multiply` example. Now if I add a line to the python source code importing a library, lets say `openpyxl`,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

I receive an error from python

```
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

I thought if I import a *system library*, I wouldn't have any problems, but I also get an error if I try to import `datetime`.

I don't have any error if I import the file from the python console. The `openpyxl` library is installed in my system.

So my question is: how to import python source code that needs to import packages?

**EDIT:** Ok, I forgot to mention something, I have not been completely honest with you guys, I'm sorry.

Trying to run the example I run into a problem: I couldn't make python found my `multiply.py` file, and the line `PyImport_Import` always return `null`.

My solution was to add the path in which I knew my python source was by using `PySys_SetPath`. The problem is that I just realized that this function doesn't append a new directory, it just overwrites the `PYTHONPATH`. So now python can find `multiply.py`, but absolutly anything else.

Of course I've deleted that line but now I have another question, why does python can't find my source if the file is just in the same directory of the C++ compiled program?

The I realized that my **`sys.path` from my python console was a little different from the path showed in my embedded python**: the first one had at the beginning of the list an empty string `''`. I'm not a python expert, but when I add that line to my path I could import the `multiply.py` so it seems that was the reason I couldn't import modules that were located to relative to my executable was the missing of this empty path -but still don't know what it means-.

I have to thank to @paul-evans who give me the idea of adding the path to find my files.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed on your system?

Comment: I have python 2.7, python 3 and python 3.3. I'm quite sure that I'm using the 2.7 version by calling `PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nprint(sys.version)");`

Comment: The `PYTHONPATH` variable is only read in `site.py`, so if for some reason your interpreter isn't reading this file your `PYTHONPATH` would be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `PYTHONPATH` is for.  You can set it as an environment variable containing a list module directories, or in the code itself something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/openpyxl/module")
```

Comment: Ok, it actually worked for finding `openpyxl` but it still fails trying to load the `datetime` package...
Do I have to append every directory my libraries needs?

Comment: Not finding the `datetime` module looks more like an install problem, but adding it to PYTHONPATH will work as a temporary fix.  Have you reorganised your python directories since install?  You might also try just reinstalling python.

Comment: I'm using the standard python 2.7.5 installed with ubuntu 13.10. And the problem finding the location doesn't occurs from the python console. 

I think this could be a temporary fix but I need to find a better one, this program is intended to work in a Windows machine :/

Comment: The problem was that I was overriding my PYTHONPATH. Finally adding `sys.path.append('')` worked for me. Thank you.